# Electrical network transfer function

Tags: laplace-transform

I am trying to solve this problem, and my answer is wrong. I suspect that I messed up the Laplace transform of the voltage source. However, I saw this in the book and thought I could simply use it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Source for Laplace transform of voltage source:

[image]

Problem:

[image]

My solution:

[image]

Answer:

[image]

Comment: Your handwriting is really difficult to follow.

Comment: I find it easier to solve it differently (but no one else seems to). The thevenin equivalent of the first loop is vi(s)/(2s+1) in series with 2s/(1+2s). Then it’s just a voltage divider:
Vo(s) = Vi(s)/(2s+1) * 3s/(3s+2/s++2s/[1+2s]). I make fewer mistakes that way, but 
it’s obvious from the way the circuit is drawn that it’s intended that it be solved with
mesh current analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use 1/s for the Laplace transform of Vg(s) ...

Made with Maple

[image]